# Show that $c(t) = \inf \{u \in \mathbb R_+: a(u) > t\}$.

Tags: probability-theory

Time changes. Let $c$ be an increasing right-continuous function from $\mathbb R_+$ into $\mathbb{\bar R}_+$. Define
$$a(u) = \inf \{t \in \mathbb R_+: c(t) > u\}, \quad u \in \mathbb R_+,$$
with the usual convention that $\inf \phi = \infty$.

a) Show that the function $a : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{\bar R}_+$ is increasing and right-continuous, and that
$$c(t) = \inf \{u \in \mathbb R_+: a(u) > t\}, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}_+.$$

For 'increasing', pick $u$ and $u'$ such that $u > u'$. Then, as $c(\cdot)$ is increasing, it is easy to see that $a(u) \ge a(u')$. For 'right-continuous', suppose not. Then, there exists $u_0$, such that $a(u_0) < a(u_0^+)$. Pick $t^* \in (a(u_0), a(u_0^+))$. This implies that $u_0 < c(t^*) \le u_0^+$, a contradiction (correct?). I am not sure how to approach the  last one. If we define $c_1(t): = \inf \{u \in \mathbb R_+: a(u) > t\}$, we have to show somehow $c_1(t) = c(t)$. I can see $c_1(t)$ is increasing and right-continuous by the same argument, but don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has to do with generalized inverses.

Since $c$ is increasing and right continuous
$$\tag{1}
a(c(t))=\inf\{\tau\in\mathbb R_+:c(\tau)>c(t)\}=t\,.
$$
I think you have correctly shown that $a$ is increasing and right continuous.
Therefore, with your notation $c_1(t):=\inf\{v\in\mathbb R_+:a(v)>t\}$, it follows
similarly to (1) that
$$\tag{2}
c_1(a(u))=u
$$
holds.
Plugging in $u=c(t)$ and using (1) we find $c_1(t)=c(t).$

Comment: Sorry. I took a day off yesterday. I think you are right. I couldn't think of $a(c(t)) = t$.